# when a button_field is presses, how do I access the node that owns the button?

Tags: 7, rules, actions

I have a button ([button_field](https://drupal.org/project/button_field)) on a content type which is rendered by a view.  The view will display a list of items and each will have a clickable button.  When the user clicks a button, I need write a rule that will set a node reference (attached to the use) to the node that was clicked.  the button_field provides several rules for detecting button clicks, but I have yet to find a rule action or rule token that gives me access to the fields on the 'node that was clicked'  How do I gain access to that node?

Edit =============

Link added.  I am using the actions that came with the module (no additional code added.) I was hoping when I used the 'button pressed' action, rules would give me accesses to entity:... so that I could use the fields on the entity (the one with the button that was pressed.)  However, this data option is not available.  Honestly, I could use flags to do this, but I thought that a flag was a bit more functionality than I needed.

Comment: If the button is a submit button, it depends what data is passed to the submit handler from that form. Presumably the node data is in the `$form_state` there.

Comment: I believe since you are clicking from a View and not the actual node, none of the node data is loaded, therefore none of that data is available to Rules. You could use it as a form submit with a custom module or have a link to the node instead and use the button on the node itself.

Comment: Could you link to the module that provides button_field? Or paste your code if it's your custom solution? Also, if it is a module, but triggers your own snippet of code, one in which you need to access node, please share that snippet.

Comment: There really is no custom code.  I am creating a rule using the UI which is based on a button click. Usually when you build a rule, the system gives you a 'triggering node' variable.  This does not exist when using button trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do something similar. It looks like as you can have button_field on any entity, you need to DEFINE what entity has button_field in your rules. It worked for me thinking like that.

What I mean is in your rules’ conditions section after checking ‘Clicked button comparison’ with your_button_field_name if you check ‘Entity is of type’ Node and ‘Content is of type’ Your_content_type, then all of the fields of your content type including nid will be available in Actions section under entity. Check out [Using Button Field](https://www.node618.com/node/90)